# Is there any easy way to pass $options to form in symfony2 rather than at new/edit all actions

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am using this in my FormType

```
->add('Task', 'entity', array(
                 'class' => 'Task',
                 'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                                     return $er->createQueryBuilder('t') 
                                     ->where('t.id = :id')
                                     ->setParameter('id',$options['id'])
```

Now for that to work i need to pass id in the form type in controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task,array('id' => $id));
```

Now it shows my form fine with all the options. But then i forgot that i also need to put the same thing in `newAction` function of controller .

Also i need to put the same in EditAction and Update action

So it means i have to repeat that at four places.

Also if ihave 4 lines which computes the `$id` then i have to repeat all those steps at four places.

On the top of that when i edit my form , then my selection is not preselected in my select box.

Then again i had to first set The object before showing in the edit form.

But if i use this without any query like this

```
->add('user')
```

Then it works without any problem, with edit functions as well.

Am i doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` being present in the newAction, I suppose it doesn't depend on the user, and is not retrieved from the url. In that case:

### **Case 1: id is not retrieved from the url:**

**Solution 1:** Injecting the entityManager directly into the form and do the logic in the form so that you don't have to repeat this in your controllers.

1- Do the logic directly within the form. Add the service needed to retrieve you `id` in the constructor.

2- Declare the form as a service, and inject the service that is needed (usually an entityManager) to get the `id` directly.

**Solution2:**
Generate the logic in an entity manager. Create a function that takes the `id` and creates the form for you. This way, you are always using the same function in your different controllers.

### **Case 2: id is retrieved from the url:**

If it is obtained from the url, you will still have to either pass the id in options or pass the id in the constructor. Passing the id as an option does not mean necessarily that you are repeating your code. It just becomes a necessity, so it has to be done.

Comment: thanks patt , i got it , what u r saying. The other main thing is that the selected options are not pre selected in edit form. Why did that happens. They are sleected if i don't use custom query, but if i use it then i manually have to preset them in editAction